# Why do messages I send display to receiver as an email address and not a phone number?

Tags: ios, messages, apple-id

My goal is when I message someone for first time it always displays my phone number.  How can I control this from my iphone5s?

Answer (score 3):

The setting for this is in Settings > Messages > Send & Recieve. From there you can scroll down to the "start new conversations from" header and choose your phone number.

Comment: The key phrase is "for the first time" - you sometimes have to delete an old history if that has your "Caller ID" as your email associated with your AppleID as the primary messaging identity. Also, you won't change how others see your messages directly - just your own phone's view of that conversation.

Comment: I am focused on how others see my messages, and what I need to change on my phone so my email is NEVER used when I send a message.